# Does Future work on App Engine?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

Does the [Future library](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/84317/) works on App Engine? If not, what is a good alternative library that does work on top of GAE?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with threading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use threading on App Engine.  See [Are there any third-party libraries not supported by Google App Engine?](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#libraries), which includes the bullet point "Threading is not available".

You might be able to accomplish what you need to accomplish via the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) api.  See [Python Threads (or their equivalent) on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917432/python-threads-or-their-equivalent-on-google-application-engine-workaround) for (slightly) more info.